# Java security framework for Amazon like REST authentication

Tags: java, security, authentication, amazon-web-services

Is there a Java security framework that provides [Amazon like](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html) REST authentication? (I am not talking about a Client for AWS, but use the same algorithm to authenticate my users.)

From the documentation:

> The Amazon S3 REST API uses a custom HTTP scheme based on a keyed-HMAC (Hash Message Authentication Code) for authentication. To authenticate a request, you first concatenate selected elements of the request to form a string. You then use your AWS Secret Access Key to calculate the HMAC of that string. Informally, we call this process "signing the request," and we call the output of the HMAC algorithm the "signature" because it simulates the security properties of a real signature. Finally, you add this signature as a parameter of the request, using the syntax described in this section.

If not, it may be possible to implement something on top of [Apache Shiro](https://shiro.apache.org), but I don't know if I am able to properly implement the algorithm above.

Comment: We have build an implementation of S3 auth for client authentication on top of spring security but i have no idea if that's portable to shiro. It's not open source but i think we could share the code if you are interested.

Comment: Another option could be restlet: http://restlet.org/learn/guide/2.1/core/security/